# Where do I find the eclEmma dependencies?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, eclemma

I'm trying to install eclEmma in my eclipse Juno installation.

When I install via 'Install new Software' eclipse calculates the dependencies, asks me to accept the licence an then produces this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.mountainminds.eclemma.asm,2.2.0.201210261515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.mountainminds.eclemma.core,2.2.0.201210261515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.mountainminds.eclemma.debug.ui.compatibility,2.2.0.201210261515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.mountainminds.eclemma.doc,2.2.0.201210261515
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.mountainminds.eclemma.feature,2.2.0.201210261515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui,2.2.0.201210261515
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jacoco.agent,0.6.0.201210061924
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jacoco.core,0.6.0.201210061924
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jacoco.report,0.6.0.201210061924
```

If I go trough the market place I get

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No artifact repository available.
noArtifactRepositoriesAvailable
```

shortly after picking what to install.

Question: What can I do to fix this? Do I need additional update sites?

Note: I just installed MoreUnit so the internet connection seems to be fine.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and manual installation of eclemma as described on the website did not work. This is what I did (on 4.3 Kepler).

Open the eclemma-2.2.1.zip.
Go to the features subdirectory.
In your eclipse/feature directory, create a directory with the name of the jar that is in the feature subdirectory of the zip file (without the jar suffix).
Now open the jar and copy its contents into this newly created directory.

When done it should look like this:

```
./eclipse/features/com.mountainminds.eclemma.feature_2.2.1.201306092145/
                   |-META-INF
                   |-about.html
                   |-feature.properties
                   |-feature.xml
```

Then copy the jars from the plugins directory inside the zip to your eclipse installation's plugins directory:

```
./eclipse/plugins/
          |-com.mountainminds.eclemma.asm_2.2.1.201306092145.jar
          |-com.mountainminds.eclemma.core_2.2.1.201306092145.jar
          |-com.mountainminds.eclemma.debug.ui.compatibility_2.2.1.201306092145.jar
          |-com.mountainminds.eclemma.doc_2.2.1.201306092145.jar
          |-com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui_2.2.1.201306092145.jar
          |-org.jacoco.agent_0.6.3.201306030806.jar
          |-org.jacoco.core_0.6.3.201306030806.jar
          |-org.jacoco.report_0.6.3.201306030806.jar
```

Start eclipse and the coverage launcher should be visible and coverage should work.

Comment: Worked for me! Installed on Kepler Eclipse for Windows. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Installation over Marketplace (Option 1) and Update Site (Option 2) didn't work also for me.

I installed it with

> [Option 3: Manual Download and Installation](http://www.eclemma.org/installation.html)

Comment: Has anyone managed to get past this? I've tried the manual download and installation both from the EclEmma website and the github repo mentioned in the EclEmma Groups.

Comment: Eclemma Manual installation failed for me. Tried on Kepler Eclipse for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install manually by following the [official documentation](http://www.eclemma.org/installation.html) but it doesn't work for me.

> Option 3: Manual Download and Installation

For manual installation please download the latest EclEmma release. Unzip the archive into dropins folder of your Eclipse installation and restart Eclipse:

```
<your eclipse installation>/
+- dropins/
   +- eclemma-x.y.z/
      +- plugins/
      |  +- ...
      +- feature/
         +- ...
```

Instead of directly placing the extracted zip file into dropins folder. I have copied all jar files available in features and plugins folder and paste manually in same features and plugin folder available under eclipse root folder respectively. Now it started working.

Solution:

```
<your eclipse installation>/
   +- plugins/
   |  +- com.mountainminds.eclemma.asm_2.3.3.201602231923
   |  +- com.mountainminds.eclemma.core_2.3.3.201602231923
   |  +- com.mountainminds.eclemma.debug.ui.compatibility_2.3.3.201602231923
   |  +- com.mountainminds.eclemma.doc_2.3.3.201602231923
   |  +- com.mountainminds.eclemma.ui_2.3.3.201602231923
   |  +- org.jacoco.agent_0.7.6.201602180812
   |  +- org.jacoco.core_0.7.6.201602180812
   |  +- org.jacoco.report_0.7.6.201602180812
   +- feature/
      +- com.mountainminds.eclemma.feature_2.3.3.201602231923
```